# Can I prevent calc() from simplifying when setting the style in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I created a function in JavaScript to apply a `style.right` to an element. Depending on the media width, I am applying one of the following three styles to it

```
listElements[i].style.right = "calc(425 * " + portfolioScrollPosition + "px)";
```

or

```
listElements[i].style.right = "calc(33.333 * " + portfolioScrollPosition + "vw)";
```

or

```
listElements[i].style.right = "calc(50 * " + portfolioScrollPosition + "vw)";
```

I need it to be written into html embedded styles EXACTLY like this. However, the `calc()` is simplifying, and is just writing something like `calc(425px)`. Is there any way to prevent JS from making this simplification?

Comment: it's because it doesn't know that your 425 number is. You must supply unit type with it, i.e. `425px`

Comment: @vanowm: there is a unit, both `px` and `vw` in the various assignments?

Comment: each value must have a unit, it's not a simple calculator as you think it is...so it would be `425px` and `33.333vw`

Comment: With multiplication only one argument needs a unit, so this should be working though since it's applying the unit it looks like `portfolioScrollPosition` is 1.

Comment: @vanowm: [nope](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/b3fo8k6y/).

Comment: oh, interesting, it does simplify when one number is 1

Comment: It depends on what you want the calculation to do. If you simply want it to multiply, why can't it "simplify" that by multiplying the two numbers when you set the numbers? There is no difference between `calc(50 * 2vw)` and `calc(100vw)`

Comment: You might consider instead of setting up values like this, set [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) instead and have CSS that would use these variables in the `calc()`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @vanowm, in `calc(..)` the end result must have a unit that is accepted by the attribute the result is assigned to. And using unitless values in `calc(..)` is perfectly legal with mult and div (*/): `calc(100vw / 5)` or `calc(425 * 5px)` both result in a legal value.

Comment: @vanowm here's some code I use daily: `:root { --a11y-scale: 1; --doc-lh: clamp(1.25, calc(-0.125 * var(--a11y-scale) + 1.625), 1.5); --doc-unit: 0.0625rem; --doc-base: calc((0.625vmin + 12 * var(--doc-unit)) * var(--a11y-scale)); }` to calculate a responsive `line-height` and `font-size` based on some a11y scale value including *px* to *rem* conversion (`--doc-unit`). Usage: `body { font-size: var(--doc-base); line-height: var(--doc-lh) }` and enable changing `--a11y-scale` with a range slider. Just showing the power of linear math in `calc(..)`.

Comment: Why do you need this be EXACTLY in this format?

Answer (score 1):

Getting it into the rendered style sheet is tricky but adding it to an elements in-line style that reads as you want it when examined in developer tools can be done by using template literals (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
Elemement.setAttribute("style", `right:calc(425 * ${portfolioScrollPosition}px;`);
```

If you really need it in the style sheet, you would have to change the inner text of the entire style element.
`<style></style>` is like any other element, you can make a reference to it and change it's inner text using `element.textContent = ""` or `element.innerText`. It will be messy with a big style sheet.

**Edit** I've made a working example to illustrate the approach of re-writing the `style` element's `innerText` here: https://jsfiddle.net/DaveCP/8czrnhwe/1/
(the SO snippet tool has trouble with new line characters in a string).

In the example, the style rule `aspect-ratio: calc(2 / 1);` is re-written to `aspect-ratio: calc(4 / 1)`